# react-bootstrap modal with form submit no work

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a Modal with react-bootstrap

[react-hook-form with fullscreen modal without form WORK](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-modal-fullscreen-work-i48lf)

But, when I add the Form the Modal works incorrectly in full screen.

[react-hook-form with fullscreen modal with form NO WORK](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-modal-fullscreen-form-submit-no-work-7b16x)

I think the problem is where to locate the Form so that it prints correctly in the html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just move `Form` to `Modal.Body`:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Col, Form, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const formRef = useRef();
  const {
    register,
    setValue,
    // handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    reset
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onChange"
  });

  function handleShow(breakpoint) {
    setShow(true);
  }

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  const onSubmitClick = () => {
    formRef.current.submit();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button className="me-2" onClick={() => handleShow("sm-down")}>
        Full screen
      </Button>
      <Modal show={show} fullscreen={true} onHide={() => setShow(false)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form
            ref={formRef}
            // onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          >
            <Form.Group as={Col} xs={12} sm={6} className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Fecha</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                {...register("fecha", { required: true })}
                isInvalid={errors?.fecha}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
              eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
              enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
              nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
              reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
              nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <Form.Group as={Col} xs={12} sm={6} className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Monto</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                {...register("monto", { required: true })}
                isInvalid={errors?.monto}
              />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={onSubmitClick} type="submit" variant="success">
            Enviar
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-bootstrap-modal-fullscreen-form-submit-no-work (forked)]

Comment: Hi, how could I launch the submit ?, the Modal.Footer is outside the Form, thanks for answering

Comment: @Kamousagi You can use `useRef` hook. I updated the code in `codesandbox`. Please check it again.